# Corrupted GZip file shows up as Data and cannot be decompressed

Tags: gzip, corruption

I have an Adobe Premiere Pro project file (.prproj) that got corrupted somehow during a network transfer. Modern .prproj files are GZip-compressed XML files, and can usually be decompressed with all the normal methods by changing the file extension to gz.

I tried to recover it with GZRT but no luck (output below). Is there anything else I can try to recover the file or is it a lost cause? Thank you very much.

Below the tests and attempts I have run so far.

**EDIT: The file is completely corrupt, hex dump shows 0x00 for the whole file. Thank you to Mark Adler for pointing out this test. Run Get a hex dump before attempting anything else, it will save you a lot of trouble!**

Simple gunzip:

```
$ gunzip corruptfile.gz
gzip: corruptfile.gz: not in gzip format
```

It doesn't get recognised as an archive:

```
$ file corruptfile.gz
corruptfile.gz: data
```

Running gzrt on it doesn't work, it results in an output of 0 bytes (original is 3466KB):

```
$ gzrecover corruptfile.gz -v
Opened input file for reading: corruptfile.gz
Opened output file for writing: corruptfile.recovered
Found error at byte 15 in input stream
Found good data at byte 0 in input stream
Found error at byte 1048577 in input stream
Found good data at byte 1048576 in input stream
Found error at byte 2097153 in input stream
Found good data at byte 2097152 in input stream
Found error at byte 3145729 in input stream
Found good data at byte 3145728 in input stream
Total decompressed output = 0 bytes
```

Running $strace gunzip corruptfile.gz:

```
execve("/usr/bin/gunzip", ["gunzip", "corruptfile.gz"], 0x7ffd5ad40cc8 /* 20 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55c05df5f000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffede6940a0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30020, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 30020, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f93d65be000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360q\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\t\233\222%\274\260\320\31\331\326\10\204\276X>\263"..., 68, 880) = 68
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2029224, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f93d65bc000
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\t\233\222%\274\260\320\31\331\326\10\204\276X>\263"..., 68, 880) = 68
mmap(NULL, 2036952, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f93d63ca000
mprotect(0x7f93d63ef000, 1847296, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f93d63ef000, 1540096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7f93d63ef000
mmap(0x7f93d6567000, 303104, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19d000) = 0x7f93d6567000
mmap(0x7f93d65b2000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7f93d65b2000
mmap(0x7f93d65b8000, 13528, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f93d65b8000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f93d65bd580) = 0
mprotect(0x7f93d65b2000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55c05c797000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f93d65f3000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f93d65be000, 30020)           = 0
getuid()                                = 1000
getgid()                                = 1000
getpid()                                = 5106
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=0x55c05c78cc30, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f93d6410210}, NULL, 8) = 0
geteuid()                               = 1000
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55c05df5f000
brk(0x55c05df80000)                     = 0x55c05df80000
getppid()                               = 5103
stat("/mnt/c/Users/KINISI/Desktop/corrupt", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=512, ...}) = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=512, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/bin/gunzip", O_RDONLY) = 3
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10
close(3)                                = 0
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
geteuid()                               = 1000
getegid()                               = 1000
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x55c05c78cc30, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f93d6410210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f93d6410210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=~[RTMIN RT_1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f93d6410210}, NULL, 8) = 0
read(10, "#!/bin/sh\n# Uncompress files.  T"..., 8192) = 2346
execve("/usr/local/sbin/gzip", ["gzip", "-d", "corruptfile.gz"], 0x55c05df5f6e8 /* 20 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/local/bin/gzip", ["gzip", "-d", "corruptfile.gz"], 0x55c05df5f6e8 /* 20 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/sbin/gzip", ["gzip", "-d", "corruptfile.gz"], 0x55c05df5f6e8 /* 20 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/bin/gzip", ["gzip", "-d", "corruptfile.gz"], 0x55c05df5f6e8 /* 20 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55d69f834000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffee339f360) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30020, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 30020, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd6152ab000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360q\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\t\233\222%\274\260\320\31\331\326\10\204\276X>\263"..., 68, 880) = 68
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2029224, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd6152a9000
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\t\233\222%\274\260\320\31\331\326\10\204\276X>\263"..., 68, 880) = 68
mmap(NULL, 2036952, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd6150b7000
mprotect(0x7fd6150dc000, 1847296, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fd6150dc000, 1540096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7fd6150dc000
mmap(0x7fd615254000, 303104, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19d000) = 0x7fd615254000
mmap(0x7fd61529f000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7fd61529f000
mmap(0x7fd6152a5000, 13528, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd6152a5000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd6150b5000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fd6152aa5c0) = 0
mprotect(0x7fd61529f000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55d69e710000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fd6152e0000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fd6152ab000, 30020)           = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGXCPU, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGXFSZ, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x55d69e6fe4b0, sa_mask=[HUP INT PIPE TERM XCPU XFSZ], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fd6150fd210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {sa_handler=0x55d69e6fe4b0, sa_mask=[HUP INT PIPE TERM XCPU XFSZ], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fd6150fd210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=0x55d69e6fe4b0, sa_mask=[HUP INT PIPE TERM XCPU XFSZ], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fd6150fd210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x55d69e6fe4b0, sa_mask=[HUP INT PIPE TERM XCPU XFSZ], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fd6150fd210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGXCPU, {sa_handler=0x55d69e6fe4b0, sa_mask=[HUP INT PIPE TERM XCPU XFSZ], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fd6150fd210}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGXFSZ, {sa_handler=0x55d69e6fe4b0, sa_mask=[HUP INT PIPE TERM XCPU XFSZ], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fd6150fd210}, NULL, 8) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(3, "corruptfile.gz", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=3548178, ...}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55d69f834000
brk(0x55d69f855000)                     = 0x55d69f855000
read(4, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 262144) = 262144
write(2, "\ngzip: corruptfile.gz: not in gz"..., 42
gzip: corruptfile.gz: not in gzip format
) = 42
close(4)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Probably a lost cause. You should provide the first 30 or so bytes in hexadecimal in your question.

Comment: Oh, I should have checked that first. It's all 0x00 from beginning to end. Definitely lost. Thanks for the heads-up.

Any idea what could cause something like this? The file was transferred from a Windows 10 PC to a Synology NAS mapped as a network drive (connection via Ethernet). Never had any corruption before. It was most likely copy-pasted via File Explorer, or there is a small chance that FreeFileSync was used. 

Just random bad luck?

Comment: I have no idea.